# How to loop all the keys in $context.authorizer in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I need to loop all the keys in $context.authorizer.key. Is there any way to loop through it? (So that I can avoid writting each key)

```
   "context" : {
       "authorizer-principal-id" : "$context.authorizer.principalId"
   }
```

I need something like this,

```
"context" : {
    #foreach($key in $context)
    "$key" : "$context.authorizer.$key"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand,
  I think you are trying to do this

```
  "context" : {
    #foreach($paramKey in $context.authorizer.keySet())
        "$paramKey" : "$context.authorizer.get($paramKey)"
     #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes exactly. Thanks piyush! Just two quick question,

Comment: 1) Correct me if I'm wrong, When these values are forward to the endpoint URL, I'm not able to get those values in body. So what I did is, 
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);    Is this correct way ?

Comment: 2) Do AWS API Gateway have change log like what they are releasing or do they have performance improvement or not ?